# Mongoose schema + nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, mongoose-schema

I'm kinda new in mongodb and i'm in trouble 
I can't reach a data from my mongo database

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Team = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
});

const MatchsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    begin_at: Date,
    number_of_games: Number,
    name: String,
    tournament: {
        name: String,
    },
    opponents: {
        type: [Team],
        default: undefined
    },
});

const Matchs = mongoose.model('matchs', MatchsSchema);

module.exports = Matchs;
```

I am trying to access with this code witch is return my "data" :

```
console.log(element.opponents[0]);
```

[data returned](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Txi4.png)

but when i want to access with .name the value is undefined

```
console.log(element.opponents[0].name);
```

database schema : [db](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5hWhG.png)

I have an collection named "teams" in my db. 
What is the problems ? I think i'm not that far...

Answer (score 0):

It might be an overlook but try...

```
console.log(element.opponents[0].opponent.name);
```

Comment: element.opponents[0].opponent is alrdy sending me back undefined so this not working aswell. Thanks for replying

Comment: The image provided from `console.log(element.opponents[0])` in your description has a field named `opponent` which holds an object with a field named `name`...

Comment: I've tryed something new and it worked, that was about the schema of "Team"

Comment: Did you use an `interface` for your `Team` definition?

Answer (score 0):

[db answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tNWi3.png)

My schema was not correct, with a modification that worked fine